# Meteor Spiderable, errors

Tags: meteor

when i test ?_escaped_fragment_= , i get

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'document.querySelectorAll.bind(document)')

http://localhost:3000/packages/material-design.js?e252ae03c7066a6ce33a348a22662a73cee8811e:75
http://localhost:3000/packages/material-design.js?e252ae03c7066a6ce33a348a22662a73cee8811e:315
http://localhost:3000/packages/material-design.js?e252ae03c7066a6ce33a348a22662a73cee8811e:318
http://localhost:3000/packages/material-design.js?e252ae03c7066a6ce33a348a22662a73cee8811e:778
```

The html in the body does show up but I do not get any meta tags and there is a huge blank space in the head before the title.

i followed http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/spiderable/ and ran phantomjs phantomtest.js

❯ phantomjs phantomtest.js                                                                [17:50:01]
Loading page...
Page load status: success
not ready, Meteor undefined

i got this.

Any idea what's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `phantomjs`, which is used by `spiderable`, the `bind` method is not supported. If you're the owner of `material-design` I would suggest replacing `bind` with `_.bind`. Otherwise, you can add [a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to your project to make sure that `Function.prototype.bind` is properly defined.

**EDIT**

To make sure your browser supports `bind` put this code somewhere in your code base:

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
  Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== 'function') {
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
      // internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');
    }

    var aArgs   = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
        fToBind = this,
        fNOP    = function() {},
        fBound  = function() {
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP && oThis
                 ? this
                 : oThis,
                 aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
  };
}
```

The above implementation is copy/pasted from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: thank you for your reply. i am quite new to web development, can you go into more details about how to do the polyfill?

Comment: thank you for your reply. i added the code but it's still giving me the same error. Material-design is a meteor package that i downloaded, could it be possible that's loading before this code gets called? and is there any way i can fix it? thanks a lot for your time

Comment: actually material-design is a package that is inside my project, so i don't understand why the polyfill doesn't fix this...

Comment: Your "polyfill" should fix it but if this particular piece of code from the package is executing before your your project then you can do nothing about it. I suggest reporting an issue on the package maintainer's page.

Comment: finally got it to work, your method works i just needed the polyfill to run before the package. thank you very much. really appreciate it.